GoRouter library can't allow me to send alert exit before exiting the app
    return Scaffold(
  key: HomePage.scaffoldKey,
  drawer: DrawerWithDropdown(),
  backgroundColor: tdWhite,
  body: WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {
      final shouldExit = await showDialog<bool>(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Confirmation'),
          content: Text('Do you want to exit?'),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
              child: Text('No'),
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
              child: Text('Yes'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
      return shouldExit == true;
    },
    child: SafeArea

the problem that i can't make a exit dialog when user want to exit the app the app exit when user press on bottom . i want to make dialog that ask the user want to exit the app. i try to make the willPopscope in the goRouter class and in main and still the app exit without showing dialiog, and this is image of class of goRoute  [enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/7YfY1veK.png i want to make the dialog in homepage

You can try the logic inside the goRouter instead on WillPopScope as such,
GoRoute(
            path: '/home',
            name: 'home',
            onExit: (context, state) async {
              final shouldExit = await showDialog<bool>(
                context: context,
                builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
                  title: const Text('Confirmation'),
                  content: const Text('Do you want to exit?'),
                  actions: [
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                      child: const Text('No'),
                    ),
                    TextButton(
                      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                      child: const Text('Yes'),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
              return shouldExit == true;
            },
            pageBuilder: (context, state) => const NoTransitionPage(
              child: HomeScreen(),
            ),
          ),

